# Woocommerce get_products return empty objects

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building custom endpoint using Woocommerce Products and the query return 6 objects but empty don't now why is that? what I'm missing on my code below?

**Code**

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

         register_rest_route( 'hash', 'related-products',array(
                 'methods' => 'GET',
                 'callback' => 'hash_realated_products'
         ));
});

function hash_realated_products() {
    // Get 10 most recent product IDs in date descending order.
    $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
                                         'limit' => 6,
                                         'status' => 'publish',
                                         'orderby' => 'rand',
                                         'tax_query' => array(
                                                              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                                              'field'    => 'term_id',
                                                              'terms'     =>  '257,352'                                                              'operator'  => 'IN'
                                                              )

                                         ) );
    $products = $query->get_products();
    return $products;

}
```

Comment: your `'terms'` should be an array of ids or an id. currently it's not. Please try `'terms'     =>  array(257,352),`

Comment: No this is not the problem and its a correct syntax, and I tried putting an array with ids still returning an empty array of objects!!! 

The objects has data but not formatted to be JSON for REST I guess, as `get_products()->get_title()` works and any specific data I need from the object I could get it but I need the whole object not parts of It.

Comment: try removing `'tax_query'` if that's really not the problem. See if it's returning something

Comment: No, It wasn't the problem and did that already as I said, the problem is I have to call the data from `products` so the final answer looping **for each** the  `$products` and each `$value` get the data like this `$array[]=$value->get_data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't call for the data from the products array!

**so the final code will be :**

```php
$products_query = $query->get_products();
$products = array();
foreach ( $products_query as $product ) {

    $products[] = $product->get_data();
}

return $products;
```