# Custom endpoint returns empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have this custom endpoint which returns orders related to a users phonenumber. I've tested the function itself in a AI (admin innit) and there its returns the whole objects. When using postman it returns 2 objects, sadly empty objects. Any ideas on why this could happend?

Tried turning the array into json and etc. Can't seem to see the solution.

I post to https://example.com/wp-json/ca/v2/orders

With the body containing an array with one item:

```
{
    "phone":    12345678
}
```

Postman returns:

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

Admin Innit returns both objects with all data.

The code:

```
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
      register_rest_route( 'ca/v2', '/orders', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'sdaasdasdasdasdasdasd',
      ) );
    } );


    // add_action('admin_init', 'sdasdasdasfasfasfasdasd');
    function sdaasdasdasdasdasdasd($request_data)
    {

        $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
        $errors = array();

        // Check if params are set.
        if(!isset($parameters) || empty($parameters))
        {
            $errors[] = 'No parameters were given';
            return $errors;
        }


        if(isset($parameters['phone']) && !empty($parameters['phone'])){

            $params = array(
                'phone'  => $parameters['phone'],
                'from'   => $parameters['from'],
                'to'     => $parameters['to'],
                'status' => $parameters['status'],
            );


            $query = new WC_Order_Query();

            if(isset($params['from']) && !empty($params['from']) && isset($params['to']) && !empty($params['to'])){

                $query->set( 'date_created', $params['from'].'...'.$params['to']);

            }

            if(isset($params['status']) && !empty($params['status'])){

                $query->set( 'status', $params['status'] );
            }

            $query->set( 'billing_phone', $params['phone'] );



            $orders = $query->get_orders();

            return $orders;
        
        }
        else
        {
            return __('You are missing the parameter: Phone', 'layback');
        }


        
        wp_die();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$orders_query = $query->get_orders();

   $orders = array();
   foreach ( $orders_query as $oOrder ) {

        $orders[] = $oOrder->get_data();
   }

return $orders;
```

Now I cant say why this solved it but my guess would be that it's because some keys are "protected" or something like that. You would have to work around that, correct me if I'm wrong. But if you ran into the same issue, the fix above works.

For very wise people, please do comment why this fixes it as I and others would love to know.

Solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400612/10999551

Comment: Private and protected information is generally considered business logic for the class, and serializers for the most part ignore these. They might hold a factory, a logger, a database connection, etc., so dumping them to JSON just doesn't make sense, or, could expose sensitive information. If you [look at the code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order.php) for that class, not only are there no public properties, that actual data lives in a single nested protected array.